# Can I find crash logs for Android Studio anywhere?

Tags: android-studio, crash-log

Since the last few weeks or so, Android Studio crashes very often for me - about once an hour.

I want to know why it crashes and the first step would be to check some crash logs... Does anyone know where to find those?

(Also please tell me if you have experienced more frequent crashes lately and if you have found out something)

Technical info:
Version: 1.5 (But also occured on the previous version, whichever that was)
OS: Mac OsX el capitan

Note: I am not asking about an Android App crash but Android Studio itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Crash logs located in:

`Library/logs/DiagnosticReports/`

No clue how to read it though.